# iOS11 user location doesn't show the blue marker

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am developing an app which asks user for location permission. I have asked for all the following permission in my info.plist file

```
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
```

My code is as follows

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    let regionRadius: Double = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        configureLocationServices()
    }

    @IBAction func centerMapbtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            centerMapOnUserLocation()
        }
    }
}

extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func centerMapOnUserLocation(){
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {
            return
        }
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius * 2, regionRadius * 2)

        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}

extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func configureLocationServices(){
        if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }else {
            return
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }

}
```

The problem is i don't see the blue marker which shows the user current location but it shows the correct area which the user is in. If I scroll to some other position in the map and click the button whose action is `centerMapbtnPressed`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `showsUserLocation` on your `MKMapView` to `true`. Seems like you haven't done that yet. (See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation) for more info)

Comment: Thanks for the help